# How do I configure tomcat to serve static content independently without modifying the web.xml file?

Tags: tomcat, web.xml, static-content

We have a very small webapp with the frontend built by a group that uses Javascript a lot.  They have so much Javascript, in fact, that the Javascript directory for common "external" Javascript (which is not application specific) is 13.2 MB.

When building, it takes a while (especially if a clean build is done) to transfer this javascript into a WAR file.  I'd like to be able to delete the external directory from the build script and serve it statically, eliminating this copying step, but I don't know how to serve static content from Tomcat without using the "default" servlet, which would require changes to the web.xml file.

How can this be done without changing the web.xml file, or any code that is currently in the WAR file?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Tomcats [VirtualWebApp](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Virtual_webapp) (example at the very bottom of the page) and [VirtualDirContext](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/resources.html#VirtualDirContext_implementation).

Comment: That VirtualDirContext looks hopeful but is a little vague on how to configure it.

Comment: It all comes down to editing the `<Context>` tag in Tomcat's `server.xml` file. You can perhaps look at the Javadocs of [VirtualDirContext](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/naming/resources/VirtualDirContext.html) and [VirtualWebappLoader](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/VirtualWebappLoader.html) as well. Just check how the `server.xml` gets used by your team - is it something you deploy each time from eg an Eclipse server configuration (the 'Servers' tab in Eclipse), or would it be okay to just edit it directly in Tomcat.